# Comparing sprites from 2 different arrays

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

In my game i have 25 shapes/color combos. these shapes will fall from the top of the screen. At the bottom i have 5 target shapes. the point of the game is to hit the falling shapes that match the target shapes.

that being said, i have 2 arrays. one creating the falling shapes and one creating the target shapes.

the thing i am having trouble with is matching them in the CCTouchesBegan method.

Logically i would think that the user would touch the sprite, get the image path of that sprite, and then compare it to the image path of the target shapes sprites. but i dont know if this is the best way too do it, or how to even get the filepath of the touched sprite.

any help would be great.

Answer (score 3):

In this case I will advice to make a custom class for your shape i.e.actually a subclass of CCSprite.
In that use an integer 'type' as its 1 of instance variables which is a unique value for every shape. It is far easier to compare objects of this class using their type as compared to actual shape.
Hope this helps. :)

Comment: sorry for the delayed answer, but yes this is exactly what i ended up doing. Thanks for the reply